# Plotting a graph with flot using sqlite db information

Tags: javascript, database, flot

I'm trying to read data from the internal sqlite database, and plot a graph using flot based
on this data.

I have an activity which inserts data into the db, accesses the db and even returns an
array with the desired data.

I also have an activity which creates a webview, and adds a javascript interface to a class
so that I can use flot and javascript to create the graph.

Both of these activities function perfectly individually but my problem lies in getting the
array of db data to a javascript interface class so that it can be accessed from javascript.

I've tried to use "Bundle.getExtra()"..etc.. to send the array from one activity to the other, but when
I go to retrieve it in the js class it can only be retrieved from the onCreate method, and hence
cannot be accessed from a javascript interface.

This is driving me crazy, any help at all would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
D

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you're working with, here.  Are you using any scripting language that is capable of writing your html?

Answer (score 1):

Note sure what you want, but here i go:

If you want to fill out some data from a query you could do it quick and easy by doing something like this in php:

```
<?php
foreach($res in $query )
{
echo "var d1 = [[0, ". $res['xxx'] ."], [1, ". $res['yyy'] ."], [2, ". $res['zzz'] ."]];";
}
?>
```

where you normally fill in the datavalues. You might even use Ajax, and then i recomend reading http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/